# Для чего нужен метод Include в Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql

Доброго времени суток уважаемые! Хочу задать наверное глупый вопрос - для чего нужен метод Include в Entity Framework? Пытался писать код и с ним и без него, проверял генерируемый SQL код с помощью LINQ Pad но не находил никакой разницы. Где этот метод бывает необходим или полезен? Что можно сделать с его помощью, чего нельзя или неудобно без него? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159621/ef-code-first-includex-x-properties-entity-a-1-many-association вот здесь неплохой пример

Comment: Include позволяет загрузить связанные сущности не при обращении к ним, а сразу.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, в коде используется Lazy Loading. Чтобы отключить его, нужно пометить все свойства `DbSet<>` класса `MyDbContext` как `virtual`. В этом случае при выполнении `.ToList()` в данных связанных объектов будет `null`. Чтобы заполнить их, потребуется принудительно указывать `.Include()`.

Comment: при отключенной *ленивой загрузке* - отсутствует модификатор `virtual` у навигационного свойства. без указания ef о необходимости подгрузить связанные сущности(`Include(), Load()`), навигационные свойства будут равны `null`