# Entity Framework include with join

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть две таблицы (по сути таблица и вьюха) и у них конечно же нет связей. То есть в table1 ентити нет table2 свойства. 
И задача - перемапить автомапером это все в клас, где есть эта связь. Пытался сделать с джойном и инклюдом, но в результате в table1withInclude нет заинклюженных сущностей.
Нужно что-то типа такого:

```
db.table1.Include(d => d.IncludeProp).Join(db.table2, // target

  c => c.CategoryId,          // FK
  cm => cm.ChildCategoryId,   // PK
  (c, cm) => new KeyValuePairTest{ table1withInclude= c, table2= cm })
```

Ну и в итоге должен быть заполненн класс

```
class CustomModel
{
IncludedProp = { filled class}
SomeJoinedPropThatEfModelDoNotHave = = { filled class}
}
```

UPD

Cтруктура таблицы:

```
table1             table2 (view)   table3 (table with real sec/prim keys, for include)
table1Id           table2Id        table3Id
Table3Id
Table2Id
```

Вью создаю самым простым способом create view select * from otherDb.table

И да. Используется db first.

UPD
Решил проблему добавлением Assosiation в модель edmx.
Правой клавишей на пустом месте - добавить Assosiation - и потом остается только удалить созданное автоматом поле и подставить свое (я это делал редактированием edmx, но может можно и как-то через интерфейс сделать).

Comment: Приведшие структуру Таблицы, вьюхи. И как делаете вьюху тоже покажите

Comment: @Bald56rus, не знаю, чем это может помочь, но добавил.

Comment: когда я говорил про структуру я имел ввиду поля и типы таблиц. а про view, раз она создается из другой таблицы приведите структуру и этой таблицы. ну и приведите пример данных и что Вы хотите получить в итоге

Comment: @Bald56rus, с самого запроса хочу получить вот что-то такое: new KeyValuePairTest{ table1withInclude= c, table2= cm }). Тип таблиц - стандартные таблицы. Нужные поля таблиц привел в первом апдейте.

Comment: насколько я знаю маппер используется для построения простых моделей, например: есть таблица пользователи, у пользователя есть отдел но в этой таблице он хранится как ID отдела, нам же надо сделать представление для пользователя где будет указано название и тогда можно использовать например [automapper](http://automapper.org/). если фактической связи между таблицами нет, то как Вы это планируете связать? Как узнать что записи из таблицы 1 сопоставима запись из таблицы 2?

Comment: @Bald56rus, была идея использовать джойн (пример в самом начале). но при джойне не работает инклюд, вот это самая главная проблема. С остальным я бы сам разобрался.

Comment: получилось ли у Вас решить проблему? если да, то напишите как Вы её решили

Comment: @Bald56rus, пока что эксплицитно подгружаю нужные связи. Это нельзя назвать решением, но слишком много дургих тасков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join - это ничто иное как

```
select
    *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
    on t1.Id==t2.t1_Id
```

т.е. соединяет таблицы по какому то полю,

[include](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/337400/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-include-%D0%B2-entity-framework?rq=1) - производит подгрузку всех необходимых данных. По умолчанию данные подгружаются по мере необходимости. а вообще это все можно настроить, но опять таки должны быть связь между таблицами.

**UPD**

опишу схему бд подходом **CodeFirst**:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}

public class OrderListView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Modified { get; set; }
}

public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public DefaultConnection()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    { }
}

var context = new ConsoleApplication1.DefaultConnection();
            var users = context.Users;
            var orders = context.Orders.Include("Users");
            var ordersWithInclude =
                    (from o in orders
                     join u in users on o.ModifiedId equals u.Id
                     select new OrderListView { Id = o.Id, Author = o.Author.LastName, Modified = u.LastName })
                     .ToList();
```

проверено работает в Entity-Framework 5.0

Comment: Да, главная проблема в том, что нет связи и быть не может, так как это вьюха. Или может?

Comment: зачем Вы привязались к view? что мешает сделать view в которой будут уже необходимые данные?! я у Вас поэтому и просил реальную структуру Вашей бд.

Comment: хм, да ничего не мешает, не думал над этим вариантом. Но это тоже не совсем красиво, тогда нужно обозвать таблицу как-то типа Table1WithTable2WithTableInclude1WithTableInclude2, к тому же в такой модели не будет никаких связей.

Comment: Вы не поняли что я Вам пытался донести, связать таблицы без физической связи не получится, может Вы не правильно пытаетесь связать? но что бы ответить на Ваш вопрос нужна структура Вашей бд с данными для примера что есть, и тогда может получится решить Вашу проблему

Comment: @sss Вам не нужно таким странным образом называть такую вьюшку. Вы же хотите сделать соединение между двумя таблицами, чтобы получить что-то конкретное, осмысленное, какую-то другую сущность или проекцию, которая имеет смысл в вашей модели. Вот ее названием и можно назвать такую вьюшку.

Comment: @ApInvent, Bald56rus, если создать вьюшку, то мы как раз таки и теряем связи с остальными сущностями, в моем случае этих связей много. К тому же  у нас в таком случае не может быть отношения один ко многим. А для каждого конкретного случая (добавить в эту вьюшку еще каккую связь)  создавать еще одну - как-то не хорошо. Связать я пытаюсь по айдишнику, что именно там может быть не правильно?

Comment: @sss Вы хотите получить ответ на свой вопрос не предоставляя всей информации. я у Вас уже неоднократно просил предоставить пример данных и структуру бд(хотя бы упрощенную, состоящую из тех таблиц с которыми Вы пытаетесь работать). На вопрос который Вы задали я Вам ответил, сделать join/include без фактической связи между таблицами невозможно

Comment: @Bald56rus, немного заапдейтил структуру, если это чем-то поможет. Связь в данном случае - наличие поля table2Id, но как таковых праймари/секондари кеев нет, да.

Comment: Да все верно, джойн по айдишникам, как вы и написали. Но нужны еще инклюды к table1.

Comment: блин, Вы меня заинтриговали.счас создам тестовый проект и внем попробую сделать тоже самое, т.е. создам три List<Table> и попробую повторить ваш подвиг

Comment: С List<Table>  вы же не сможете протестировать Include.

Comment: @SSS давайте в чате я у Вас уточню некоторые моменты

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29432/discussion-between-sss-and-bald56rus).

Answer (score 1):

Нет никаких проблем в EF соединить две таблицы, даже если по ним нет соединения через навигационные свойства.

Если есть таблица `T1` с полями `a`, `b` и таблица `T2` с полями `b`, `c`, Вы можете собрать из них третий класс `T3 (a, c)`, например так:

```
var result = from t1 in dbContext.Set<T1>()
             join t2 in dbContext.Set<T2>() on t1.b equals t2.b
             select new T3(t1.a, t2.c);
```

Это касается, естественно, не только таблиц (tables), но и представлений (views).

Конечно, можно использовать и метод `Include`:

```
var result = from t1 in dbContext.Set<T1>()
                                 .Include(x => x.Table2)
                                 .Include(x => x.Table3)
             join t2 in dbContext.Set<T2>() on t1.b equals t2.b
             select new T3(t1.a, t2.c);
```

Вы сразу можете создавать объекты `CustomModel` или сначала создавать некие промежуточные объекты (в примере они относятся к классу `T3`), чтобы затем замапить их на `CustomModel`.

Comment: что бы можно было сделать связь при помощи join должно быть поле, в котором одна таблица ссылается на другую. вот этого то я и хотел добиться от автора. что бы можно было написать конкретный ответ. в вашем примере  это t1.b ==t2.b

Comment: @Bald56rus Вы правы, вопрос задан довольно сумбурно. Я надеюсь, автор вопроса уловит направление, и сможет правильно распорядиться ответом.

Comment: Сделать джойн действительно нет никаких проблем (к тому же я его в вопрос включил как пример первым). Но как теперь сделать, чтоб в ваш t1 заинклюдились связанные сущности? @Bald56rus,Извиняюсь, что вопрос несколько размыт, но я там написал и уже несколько раз говорил, что поле айдишника у меня есть.

Comment: @sss Метод `Include` не мешает использовать `Join`. Подправил свой ответ.

Comment: если я не ошибаюсь то что бы сработал Include должно быть навигационное свойство - связь, как раз таки то что как утверждает тс нету, а иначе как знать что надо подгрузить

Comment: @Bald56rus Вроде как там есть два навигационных свойства в `table1`, по ним должен работать `Include`. И `join` с другой таблицей, с которой нет навигационной связи, тоже будет работать. Насколько я понял, в этом и был вопрос.

Comment: да соглашусь с Вами, единственное вызывают сомнения по поводу join с view. да сделать можно, но нужно ли?

Comment: @Bald56rus, если не было бы нужно, не было бы этого вопроса :).  Mark Shevchenko, вы правильно меня понимаете, но после джойна инклюд пропадает. В моем самом первом примере в KeyValuePairTesеt.table1withInclude нет инклюда, который я обьявлял в самом начале. В вашем втором примере заинклюженные сущности пропадут.

Comment: @sss Я сейчас проверил, похоже, у вас какая-то другая ошибка. После `join` у меня не пропадают навигационные свойства, явно перечисленные в `Include`.

Comment: Mark Shevchenko, у вас отключен lasy loading, какая версия ентити?

Comment: @sss http://pastie.org/10439213 — это мои файлы. После вашей реплики я отключил lazy loading (убрал ключевые слова virtual из навигационных свойств), результат не изменился. EF версии 6.1.3.

Comment: Спасибо, возможно дело в версии EF. Или в построении запроса, я использую запрос как в своем первом примере, попробую еще поэксперементировать чуть позже.

Comment: @sss Вы можете взять файлы, добавить в новый консольный проект, и инсталлировать вашу версию EF. Это позволит быстро проверить, в версии ли дело. Я подозреваю, что всё-таки нет.