# MS SQL, EF, Коллекции не подгружаются

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток.

Создаю бд по принципу Code-first.
Имею следующие классы:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        Product = new List<Product>();
    }

}
class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext()
        : base("DbConnection"){ }

    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Создаю объекты, записываю в базу.

К слову - база - ***(localdb)\v11.0*** в файле **.mdf** (грубо говоря первый раз с EF работаю).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
        {
            // AddToDataBase(db);
            // получаем объекты из бд и выводим на консоль
            Console.Clear();
            var orders = db.Orders.ToList();
            foreach (var order in orders)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", order.Id, order.Customer);

                if (order.Product.Count > 1)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    foreach (var pr in dp.Product)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", pr.Id, pr.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void AddToDataBase(UserContext db)
    {
        var pr1 = new Product() { Name = "phone" };
        var pr2 = new Product() { Name = "car" };
        db.Products.Add(pr1);
        db.Products.Add(pr2);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var ord1 = new Order() { Customer = "Denis", Product = new Collection<Product>() { pr1 } };
        var ord2 = new Order() { Customer = "test", Product = new Collection<Product>() { pr2 } };
        Console.WriteLine("Объекты созданы.");
        db.Orders.Add(ord1);
        db.Orders.Add(ord2);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("Объекты успешно сохранены");
    }
```

Делаю работу по примеру.

После первого запуска выполняю метод **AddToDataBase**.
Во время второго запуска хочу просто вывести данные, прочитанные из бд.
Но в итоге выводит, что у каждого Order внутри коллекции **Product** 0 элементов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда смотреть и как решить?

Думал изменить структуру, но будет ли это правильным?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если Вы используете подход code first то модификатор доступа `virtual` должен быть установлен у навигационных свойств `public virtual Order Order {get;set;}`

В этом случае у Вас будет возможность получить значение из связанной таблицы при обращении к навигационному свойству, в ином случае Вам необходимо сообщить ef о необходимости подгружении связанных сущностей при помощи методов`Include()` или `Load()`

---

в классе описывающем контекст у `DbSet` модификатор доступа `virtual` не нужен. о возможных способах получения связанных сущностей чуть более подробно можно посмотреть в моем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482282/179270)

Answer (score 3):

```
var orders = db.Orders.Include("Product").ToList();
```

если верить [этому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/426086/215651) то:

> Если `DbSet<>` помечен как `virtual`, в этом случае при выполнении `.ToList()` в данных связанных объектов будет `null`. Чтобы заполнить их, потребуется принудительно указывать `.Include()`.

Comment: Хм, спасибо, пробовать не буду - знаю, что сработает.

Но разве это правильно? 

А насчет virtual - ранее писал без него - была аналогичная проблема.

Comment: на сколько я знаю модификатор доступа `virtual` должен быть у навигационного свойства